# pygame.sprite giving error RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

Tags: pygame

My game's code is a simple platform game, but when  try to add sprites, it gives me an error with `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object`

I follow a rough tutorial and try to modify the code for myself, i'm quite new to coding so can anyone help solve this?

Ive seen people turn the recursion into a loop, which i don't understand what it is.

```
class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite()):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load('image/spida.png')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
```

heres the chunk of code that is giving me an error, the specific part is `pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)` it highlights the `self` part, saying `Expected type 'Sprite', got 'Enemy' instead`(this is in the project errors part of code)

Comment: Remove () in `class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite()):`. It should be `class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):`. Not sure if that is whats causing your problem though. Try it and see if it fixes it

Comment: It is a typo: `pygame.sprite.Sprite()` creates a new instance. `class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite()):` must be `class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):`

Comment: @user16038533 ah thanks so much, i was trying so many ways to fix it. Thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in your code `pygame.sprite.Sprite()`creates a new instance object. Change:

<s>`class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite())`:</s>

```py
class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite)
```